# firebase RecaptchaVerifier showing argument-error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was trying to enable phone number authentication using firebase on my react js project. According to firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?authuser=0) to enable phone number authentication I need to set up ReCaptcha verifier first. I have installed the latest version of firebase (9.0.2). But for some reason, I'm getting an argument error from the `new RecaptchaVerifier()` method.

[image]

[image]

I don't think I am getting this error for the wrong firebase config. Because other methods like signInWithGoogle are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I have used `className` instead of `id`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).